# Android XML Configuration File?

Tags: android, exchange-server

I work for an enterprise service desk, and many of our users use Android phones. On the other hand, some of our users also use iPhones, and we were able to create a profile that a user can download to setup their exchange account. Is there any programs that allow this to be done for Android? We are looking to streamline our exchange account setup, and we would like a similar configuration file for the Android phones.

Or if there is no configuration utility, does anyone know of any enterprise solution for Android exchange setup?

Comment: You mean that this configuration file would be read by the default email application, and then the account would be set up?

Comment: Ya, basically, with iOS you can make a configuration profile a user downloads. Then it asks simple questions like what is your email and password. The configuration profile holds all of our pertinent information such as ports and server, so once they enter their info, it adds the correct exchange account. We are looking to do the same with android. Apple calls their version of it "iPhone Configuration Utility." (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such feature in the Android Email App. You need to manually set up your phones to talk to any exchange servers.