# Android Configuration File for email account?

Tags: android, xml, email, configuration

I wish to explore the feasibility of setting up a Android configuration file for email accounts with all the mail settings like pop/imap, smtp in that file.

This configuration file can be downloaded & installed from say a server end point.

Is there such a configuraiton utility available for Android?

As per the below post /answer - it is not available.

[Android XML Configuration File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623688/android-xml-configuration-file/44381837#44381837)

However above post is 2012...so is there such a feature available in latest Android version for Email configuration profiles?

Please suggest.
Thanks,
Ajinkya